# Problem creating a smooth transition between Vuejs components of various heights using vue-router

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js, vue-router

Okay, so basically I'm basically trying to use vue-router to switch components inside a basic container on the fly. The thing is that I want to animate the transition, but I'm having a problem doing it smoothly since all elements have different heights. If you want to see what I'm trying to do, you can check it on codepen [here](https://codepen.io/osuwariboy/pen/NWKgMGN). Just click on "Component 2" and you'll see what I mean.

As you can see, I'm using these four methods to control the appearance of the container as well as the display of the components while they're transitioning so they don't stagger each other (which looks rather horrible):

```
beforeEnter: function(el){

    this.$refs['container'].style.height = getComputedStyle(this.$refs['container']).height;

    el.style.width = getComputedStyle(this.$refs['container']).width;
    el.style.position = "absolute"; 
},

beforeLeave: function(el){

    this.$refs['container'].style.height = getComputedStyle(this.$refs['container']).height;
    el.style.position = "absolute";
    el.style.width = width;
},

afterEnter: function(el){
    el.style = "";
    this.$refs['container'].style.height = 'auto';
},

afterLeave: function(el){
    el.style = "";
    this.$refs['container'].style.height = 'auto';
},
```

In an ideal world, I'd like to have the height of the container gradually transition from its current value to its new value. However, I'm faced with two problems:

1) The new height is not known until the transition's over and the new component is in place (which makes sense when you think about it).

2) The height transition must happen on the container, not the actual element that's currently sliding in/out.

Does anyone have any idea how to solve this and create a smooth transition between my various components?